# How to Know the Estimated Time That an Animation Will Fully Render?

Tags: rendering, animation

I have finished an animation and am going to fully render it.

Is there a way to know the estimated time of how long a whole animation will take to render?

I mean the whole animation, not just each frame. Like when you render something it shows on the top of the animation:                       Frame: 0|Last: 00:00.00 Time: 00:00.00 | Remaining 00:00.00|

Is there something that will calculate the time that it will take for the whole animation to render?

Comment: I don't think there is. You can always render a single frame and calculate `time_for_frame * number_of_frames`, but there's no way to know if the coming frames are going to be less or more render-intensive.

Comment: That's what I assumed, thank you so much for the help!